# Is "using namespace std;" exempted from the Excessive Code Rule?

Tags: c++

The rules at
http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=help&d2=ratedEvent
specify that Library import statements (#include, imports, using, Imports) are exempted. 
But in C++, using statement is not for importing a library.

Can anybody please confirm that is `using namespace std;` exempted from the Excessive / Extra Code Rule, or not?

Answer (score 0):

It can be disputed if `using namespace std;` would be excessive; it fulfils a function, but rather a syntactical one than a functional one.

Using it, though, is [never such a good idea anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) (since it pollutes the current namespace), therefore I would recommend not to use it in any case. There's nothing wrong with a few `std::` prefixes in your code, it's not that much to write and then at least one sees easily what comes from std namespace!

Comment: It is reasonable to use it in Topcoder SRM. You know, every second counts there. By saving a dozen of `std::`s you may earn two more score.